# Reading binary data from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, jetty

Using Jetty, I'm sending bytes to URL `http://localhost:8080/input/` like so -

```
public static void sampleBytesRequest (String url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.start();

        client.newRequest(url)
              .content(new InputStreamContentProvider(new ByteArrayInputStream("batman".getBytes())))
              .send();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

My server (also Jetty) has a handler like so -

```
public final class JettyHandler extends AbstractHandler implements JettyConstants, LqsConstants
{
@Override
public void handle (String target,
                    Request baseRequest,
                    HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
             throws IOException, ServletException
{
    response.setContentType(UTF_ENCODING);

    String requestBody = null;
    try { requestBody = baseRequest.getReader().readLine(); }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

     System.out.println(new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getInputStream())));
}
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to recreate the original string from the binary data and print it to stdout.

However, if I set a break point at the print statement in the handler, when the request reaches that line, the server abruptly seems to skip over it.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the binary data I'm sending over and recreate the string?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you read a line from the request reading the bytes from the stream?

Comment: @JBNizet The baseRequest contains some important information from other requests I send to the handler. I think it's distinct from the request I'm trying to print from.

Comment: Make up your mind. Either you want binary or you want to read lines. They are mutually exclusive. If you want to read a line, send a line, with a line terminator.

Comment: Ack! I can't decide! T_T

Comment: Seriously, though, there are some times I read the Request, other times I read the HttpServletRequest. I send binary data for some cases, form data for others.

Comment: I omitted the switch logic for brevity.

Comment: FYI: `request` and `baseRequest` are the same object.  Also, like others have pointed out, accessing `.getReader()` and `.getInputStream()` on the same exchange is forbidden (you only have 1 request body content to read, once its read you can't read it again)

Comment: That is incredibly useful information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with my client.

Instead of

```
client.newRequest(url)
          .content(new InputStreamContentProvider(new ByteArrayInputStream("batman".getBytes())))
          .send();
```

The proper way to do this is -

```
client.newRequest(url)
      .content(new BytesContentProvider("batman".getBytes()), "text/plain")
      .send();
```